# content editable is disabled by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found a code that can clone drag and drop element. But when I try to add some div tag which is contenteditable, the div is not editable. I inspect it with mozila, and found out that it is because jquery add some function to the parents div such as mousedown, mouseup, and etc.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Klaudia/htgsdqos/

Note: I got this code from SO too: (So, it's not mine)

HTML :

[image]

Jquery:

```
$("#left-pane li").draggable({
    containment: '#gbox',
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    scroll: false,
    connectToSortable: '#right-pane',
    appendTo: '#right-pane',
    start: function () {},
    stop: function (event, ui) {}
}).mousedown(function () {});

$("#right-pane").sortable({
    sort: function () {},
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    receive: function () {},
    update: function (event, ui) {}
});


$("#right-pane").droppable({
    accept: "#left-pane li",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.draggable).find('.single-item').length == 0)
        {
            $(ui.draggable).append("<div class='single-item'><input type='text' class='item-title' /><br /><textarea class='item-text'></textarea></div>");
        }
    }
});

$("#left-pane").droppable({
    accept: "#right-pane",
    drop: function (event, ui) {}
});

$("ul, li").disableSelection();
```

So my question is, how to keep the div content is editable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: The js fiddle is included in the question. No, problem. I just solve it. It is because of this line `$("ul, li").disableSelection();`